# What are the possible ways to write spec for a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a method in my model called average_n.

```
  def average_n=(average_n)
     @average_n = average_n
  end
```

I wrote rspec as follows

```
 its 'should be 8' do
   model.average_n=8.should==8
 end
```

Is there any other possible way to write rspec for this method?. If yes please post as answer.

Comment: There are any number of other ways to write a spec for this method? What are you trying to achieve? What do you wish was different and why? What do you think is important in how you write a spec?

Comment: the above one was rejected by client. so i want to write in another way.

Comment: Again, why was it rejected? What problem do you see with this which you want to solve? "Give me another way" is not a useful question because there is no way to evaluate an answer.

Comment: model.average_n=8.should==8 is this correct?

Comment: What does "correct" mean? If the parser accepts it is it correct? If it passes and fails as you expect is it correct? If it makes your client happy is it correct? There is no way for us to judge what counts as a good answer here so all you are going to get is assumptions about what you are really asking and opinions about what tests should look like.

Comment: @Jonah got solution from infused .

Comment: @Jonah Deep breaths... hahaha!

Comment: Your existing spec doesn't actually test much - it is parsed as `average_n = (8.should == 8)`

Comment: yes @FrederickCheung. i changed as per the answer given by infused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the setter method (`average_n=`), so you'll also need a getter method:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def average_n
    @average_n
  end

  def average_n=(average_n)
    @average_n = average_n
  end
end
```

This can be simplified using `attr_accessor`:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :average_n
end
```

If you really need to write a spec for it:

```
describe '#average_n=' do
  let(:my_model) { MyModel.new }

  it 'sets average_n' do
    my_model.average_n = 8
    expect(my_model.average_n).to eq 8
  end
end
```